# The method AsQueryable is not supported in the expression tree mongodb linq

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have written below linq query for mongodb and getting exception
"The method AsQueryable is not supported in the expression tree:"

```
   var result=from data in database.GetCollection<CollectionName>("CollectionName").AsQueryable()
          select new CollectionName
{
Property=data.Field.AsQueryable().Skip(1).Take(10)
}
```

Comment: Hi .. Linq driver for mongo is not mature as the one for EF ... have you just tried to remove the queryable and do something like: data.Field.Skip(1).Take(10)

Comment: @federico-scamuzzi thanks!. Removing  AsQueryable working fine.

Comment: so i post as answer for other people... if you can rate it..thnx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove AsQueryable like this:

```
var result=from data in database.GetCollection<CollectionName>("CollectionName").AsQueryable()
          select new CollectionName
{
Property=data.Field.Skip(1).Take(10)
}
```